# How to move nav-link to the right in bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigation

I would like to ask how to move nav-link to the right? becuase I try it like float: right or margin left:auto,it will lead hamburger menu to the middle. I want the hamburger menu and navlink all to right side. Besides, when I minimize my screen smaller, the hamburger menu and navlink are fine they are in right side, just when I minimize my screen bigger, the nav-link is at the left side. Also, when I minimize the screen smaller, I click the dropdown menu, the navbar become bigger and the dropdown menu is inside the navbar which lead the navbar bigger. I want the dropdownmenu outside the navbar. I try to use position: fixed, position :relative and position absolute, it doesn't fix it. Therefore, I would like to ask is there any solutions about. So, I can fix it. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

This my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"

 integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 

crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!--Icon-->

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" 

integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" 

crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>Admin Dashboard</title>

    <style>

       /*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */

  padding: 48px 0 0; /* Height of navbar */

  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {

  .sidebar {

    top: 5rem;

  }

}

.sidebar-sticky {

  position: relative;

  top: 0;

  height: calc(100vh - 48px);

  padding-top: .5rem;

  overflow-x: hidden;

  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */

}

@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {

  .sidebar-sticky {

    position: -webkit-sticky;

    position: sticky;

  }

}

.sidebar .nav-link {

  font-weight: 500;

  color: #333;

}


.sidebar .nav-link.active {

  color: #021B4D;

}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover {

  color: #FFDB1A !important;

}


/*Navbar*/

 .navbar{

           background-color:#021B4D  !important;
          
       }
      
      
.navbar-brand {

  padding-top: .75rem;

  padding-bottom: .75rem;

  font-size: 1rem;

  margin-left:20px;

}

.white-text{

  color:#fff;

}

.dropdown-menu a:hover{

    background-color:#021B4D;

    color:#fff;

}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top  ">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">

      <img src="eGrocery_SDP(Logo).jpeg" width="50" height="40">

    </a>

    <button class=" navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-

target="#sidebarMenu"

    aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-

left:auto;"><span class="white-text"><i

        class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>

    <ul class="navbar-nav  " >

     <li class="nav-item dropdown  " >

      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown-target"  href="#"><i 

  class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:40px;color:#fff;"></i></a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Account</a>

            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a href="#"class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>

        </div>

      </li>

     </ul>

   </nav>
      
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">

    <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-5">

      <ul class="nav flex-column">

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">

            <span data-feather="home"></span>

            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="file"></span>

            Products

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>

         Orders

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="users"></span>

            Manage Customers

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>

           Manage Staff

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="layers"></span>

           Sales Reports

          </a>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-

KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 

integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-

JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the user icon always to the right, I added this css:

```
a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle{
  text-align: right;
}
```

Then on large screen to keep your `ul` always to the right I add BS4 class `ml-lg-auto` that will add margin au to the left for screen over lg break points.

For having hambuger align right add class `ml-left` to your button.

If you want to have the same effect of your dropdown in small and large screen I added css as follow:

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .user-dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -6rem !important;
  }
}
```

```css
a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle{
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-width: 991px){
  .user-dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -6rem !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"

 integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 

crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!--Icon-->

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" 

integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" 

crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>Admin Dashboard</title>

    <style>

       /*
 * Sidebar
 */

.sidebar {

  position: fixed;

  top: 0;

  bottom: 0;

  left: 0;

  z-index: 100; /* Behind the navbar */

  padding: 48px 0 0; /* Height of navbar */

  box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);

}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {

  .sidebar {

    top: 5rem;

  }

}

.sidebar-sticky {

  position: relative;

  top: 0;

  height: calc(100vh - 48px);

  padding-top: .5rem;

  overflow-x: hidden;

  overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */

}

@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {

  .sidebar-sticky {

    position: -webkit-sticky;

    position: sticky;

  }

}

.sidebar .nav-link {

  font-weight: 500;

  color: #333;

}


.sidebar .nav-link.active {

  color: #021B4D;

}

.sidebar .nav-link:hover {

  color: #FFDB1A !important;

}


/*Navbar*/

 .navbar{

           background-color:#021B4D  !important;
          
       }
      
      
.navbar-brand {

  padding-top: .75rem;

  padding-bottom: .75rem;

  font-size: 1rem;

  margin-left:20px;

}

.white-text{

  color:#fff;

}

.dropdown-menu a:hover{

    background-color:#021B4D;

    color:#fff;

}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top  ">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">

      <img src="eGrocery_SDP(Logo).jpeg" width="50" height="40">

    </a>

    <button class=" navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-

target="#sidebarMenu"

    aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="margin-

left:auto;"><span class="white-text"><i

        class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>

    <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-lg-auto" >

     <li class="nav-item dropdown  " >

      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown-target"  href="#"><i 

  class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:40px;color:#fff;"></i></a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu user-dropdown-menu"  aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">

          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Account</a>

            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a href="#"class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>

        </div>

      </li>

     </ul>

   </nav>
      
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">

    <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-5">

      <ul class="nav flex-column">

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">

            <span data-feather="home"></span>

            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="file"></span>

            Products

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>

         Orders

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="users"></span>

            Manage Customers

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>

           Manage Staff

          </a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">

          <a class="nav-link" href="#">

            <span data-feather="layers"></span>

           Sales Reports

          </a>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-

KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 

integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-

JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks you. But I would I would like to ask how to move hamburger menu to the right  which next with the dropdown menu? Cause when you minimize it, the hamburger menu is at middle.

Comment: And the dropdownmenu ( minimize in small screen) , doesn't same as large screen.

Comment: @CharlotteChee For the hamburger that done (edited). You only need to add `ml-auto` on your button. For your the dropdown, you mean, that you would like to have it like in position absolute like in larger screen ?